# Introduction to C# list comprehensions

Tags: c#, linq

How can I perform list comprehensions in C#?

Comment: I guess you mean collection initializer when you say list comprehension. Correct?

Answer (score 69):

Found this when I was looking up how to do list comprehensions in C#...

When someone says list comprehensions I immediately think about Python. The below code generates a list that looks like this:

```
[0,2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18]
```

The Python way is like this:

```
list = [2*number for number in range(0,10)]
```

In C#:

```
var list2 = from number in Enumerable.Range(0, 10) select 2*number;
```

Both methods are lazily evaluated.

Comment: Python constructs the whole list, it's not lazily evaluated. In Python if you want lazy evaluation, use a generator expression. Syntactically, instead of square brackets use parentheses.

Answer (score 69):

A List Comprehension is a type of set notation in which the programmer can describe the properties that the members of a set must meet. It is usually used to create a set based on other, already existing, set or sets by applying some type of combination, transform or reduction function to the existing set(s).

Consider the following problem: You have a sequence of 10 numbers from 0 to 9 and you need to extract all the even numbers from that sequence. In a language such a C# version 1.1, you were pretty much confined to the following code to solve this problem:

```
ArrayList evens = new ArrayList();
ArrayList numbers = Range(10);
int size = numbers.Count;
int i = 0;

while (i < size) 
{
    if (i % 2 == 0) 
    {
        evens.Add(i);
    }
    i++;
}
```

The code above does not show the implementation of the Range function, which is available in the full code listing below. With the advent of C# 3.0 and the .NET Framework 3.5, a List Comprehension notation based on Linq is now available to C# programmers. The above C# 1.1 code can be ported to C# 3.0 like so:

```
IEnumerable<int> numbers = Enumerable.Range(0, 10);
var evens = from num in numbers where num % 2 == 0 select num;
```

And technically speaking, the C# 3.0 code above could be written as a one-liner by moving the call to *Enumarable.Range* to the Linq expression that generates the *evens* sequence. In the C# List Comprehension I am reducing the set *numbers* by applying a function (the modulo 2) to that sequence. This produces the *evens* sequence in a much more concise manner and avoid the use of loop syntax. Now, you may ask yourself: Is this purely syntax sugar? I don't know, but I will definitelly investigate, and maybe even ask the question myself here. I suspect that this is not just syntax sugar and that there are some true optimizations that can be done by utilizing the underlying monads.

The full code listing is available [here](http://thestandardoutput.com/2009/06/list-comprehensions-in-c/).

Comment: Upvoted, but just a quick note that your first code snippet creates `ArrayList numbers` but then doesn't use it.

Comment: @joseville the line of code above that reads `int size = numbers.Count;` is using `numbers`, is it not?

Comment: Yes, you're right! The snippet can be clarified:

```
ArrayList evens = new ArrayList();
int minNum = 0;
int maxNum = 10;
int num = 0;

while (num <= maxNum) 
{
    if (num % 2 == 0) 
    {
        evens.Add(num);
    }
    num++;
}
```

(Sorry, comments don't format code snippets well.)

Answer (score 10):

@Ian P

```
 return (from user in users
         where user.Valid
         select user.Name).ToArray();
```

Comment: He didn't specify LINQ, so I just went as basic as possible. Your example is definitely preferred.

Answer (score 4):

You can use LINQ to make expressions that are similar to list comprehensions. Here's a site explaining it a little:

[List Comprehension in C# with LINQ](http://artyprog.blogspot.com/2008/07/list-comprehension-in-c-with-linq.html)

[List Comprehension in C# with LINQ - Part 2](http://artyprog.blogspot.com/2008/07/list-comprehension-in-c-with-linq-part.html)

Answer (score -9):

While this isn't a tutorial, here's some code that illustrates the concept:

```
public List<string> ValidUsers(List<User> users) {
  List<string> names = new List<string>();
  foreach(User user in users) {
    if(user.Valid) {
      names.Add(user.Name);
    }
  }
  return names;
}
```

Comment: This is not list comprehension.