# How to fill and Array of doubles with elements numbered 1 thru 15

Tags: c#, arrays

How can  I duplicate this functionality with a loop.

```
string[] titles = new string[] { "Alpha", "Beta", "Gamma", "Delta" };
List<double[]> x = new List<double[]>();
for (int i = 0; i < titles.Length; i++)
{
 // Replace this line of code
   x.Add(new double[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15 });
}
```

So that I can use a variable e.g. temp =  15 which would be the doubles 1.0 .... 15.0

Comment: Are you looking for terse code?  Try a list comprehension.

Comment: I didnt really understand the question..? What's wrong with your code right now?

Comment: Why did the other answers get downvoted, they are perfectly reasonable.

Answer (score 2):

```
var result = titles
    .Select(t => Enumerable.Range(1, 15).Select(i => (double)i).ToArray())
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Who ever it is I think they're protesting the LINQ-only solutions. Bit rough if you ask me.

Comment: Why go against LINQ - it's so powerful

Answer (score 2):

If I'm allowed to use LINQ then how about this?

```
var titles = new string[]
{
    "Alpha", "Beta", "Gamma", "Delta",
};

Func<int, double[]> makeArray = n =>
    (from i in Enumerable.Range(1, n) select (double)i)
        .ToArray();

var temp = 15;

var x = (from t in titles
         select makeArray(temp)).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

Using a simple for loop

```
List<double> nums = new List<double>();
for ( int i = 0; i < target; i++ ) {
    nums.Add( (double)i );
}
```

You could use the `Linq Enumberable` class in lieu of a loop.

```
using System.Linq;

int target = 15;    
var nums = Enumerable.Range(0, target).Select( x => (double)x);
```

Comment: Or in C# 3.0, with list comprehensions.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/130898/introduction-to-c-list-comprehensions