# How to simplify array extraction values

Tags: python

Is there an easier way to parse an array with a list inside from this:

```
data = [{'id': '1456', 'type': 'hotel', 'money': '123'}, 
{'id': '3215', 'type': 'appartment', 'rooms': '2', 'toilet': '1'},
{'id': '3213', 'type': 'hotel', 'money': '999'}]
```

To this:

```
hotel = ['123, '999']
```

I want to extract from the `data` array the money value just for the `type` hotel and append everything into one array.

I wanted to avoid creating a loop, and iterating over it and then checking if there is a `key` called money. And if so, extract it and append to a `hotel` array.

It seems a bit redundant for Python, I guess..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yeah, you can use a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
hotels = [d['money'] for d in data if d['type'] == 'hotel']
```

This will effectively look through the `data` array and extract each dictionary as `d`, then only add `d['money']` to the resulting array if the type is `'hotel'`.

Answer (score 1):

Use [list comprehension](http://www.secnetix.de/olli/Python/list_comprehensions.hawk) for that

The list comprehension allows you to construct a list based another list and you can use conditions to select only the values you need.

```
list = [x['money'] for x in data if x['type'] == 'hotel']
```

Answer (score 1):

A more functional style would be something like the toolz library.

http://toolz.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html#toolz.itertoolz.pluck

List comprehension work also, but I find them extremely ugly, when compared to something like LINQ

Comment: You do realize that LINQ and list comprehensions are basically the same thing, right? In fact, [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/130898/introduction-to-c-sharp-list-comprehensions) is the first result for a search on "C# list comprehensions".

Comment: @AlexVanLiew They do some similar things, but they are not the same. LINQ is more terse and works better if you have to do nested queries. Also grouping etc. flows more natural in LINQ

Answer (score 1):

[Pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/10min.html) approach:

```
In [15]: df = pd.DataFrame(data)

In [16]: df
Out[16]:
     id money rooms toilet        type
0  1456   123   NaN    NaN       hotel
1  3215   NaN     2      1  appartment
2  3213   999   NaN    NaN       hotel

In [17]: df.ix[df.type == 'hotel']
Out[17]:
     id money rooms toilet   type
0  1456   123   NaN    NaN  hotel
2  3213   999   NaN    NaN  hotel

In [18]: df.ix[df.type == 'hotel', 'money']
Out[18]:
0    123
2    999
Name: money, dtype: object

In [19]: df.ix[df.type == 'hotel', 'money'].tolist()
Out[19]: ['123', '999']
```

One-liner:

```
In [20]: pd.DataFrame(data).ix[df.type=='hotel', 'money'].tolist()
Out[20]: ['123', '999']
```

Answer (score 1):

A functional approach might look something like:

```
filter(len, (d.get('money', '') for d in data))
```

The `dict.get` part gets the `money` value from each dictionary, returning the empty string if it's not there. Then, `filter` is used to remove all empty strings.